# PHP - foreach looping double

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this funny feeling like this is going to be something simple that my tired eyes have missed.

Given the following array `$query`:

```
Array ( [report_id] => 19 [facebook_id] => Array ( [0] => 12345678 [1] => 12345678 [2] => 12345678 [3] => 12345678 [4] => 12345678 ) )
```

(Never mind the values of the `[facebook_id]` array, I just put that in there for the example)

I need to iterate over and pass each value to a function. I'm using the following foreach loop, and when I test how many times it's looping it goes through double.

```
foreach ($query as $value) {
    $report_id = $query['report_id'];
    $looper = $query['facebook_id'];
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($looper as $inner) {
        if ($i == 0) {
            $facebook_id_list = $inner;
        } else {
            $facebook_id_list = $facebook_id_list.'|'.$inner;
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

The output when I echo everything back is:

```
19
12345678|12345678|12345678|12345678|12345678
19
12345678|12345678|12345678|12345678|12345678
```

I'm eventually going to explode the `$facebook_id_list` in my function, that's why I'm concatenating the multi-dimensional array into the variable.

What am I missing?

Comment: you are over writing your sting not adding to it, also sounds like you should be creating a new array instead of the sting.

Comment: in **$looper = $query['facebook_id'];** .. is it 'facebook_id' as string or var ?

Comment: Why not `$facebook_id_list = implode('|', $query['facebook_id'])`?

Comment: I also wasn't unsetting the variables properly. I ended up greatly simplifying the final version so if anyone comes across this and has a similar issue just message me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop can be replaced with:

```
$report_id = $query['report_id'];
$facebook_id_list = implode('|', $query['facebook_id']);
```

No loop, no looping twice.

Comment: My fault for not being clear - that array may return more than one set of values depending on the SQL query.

Comment: The array you showed is just one row, it can't have more than one set of values. You need to repeat this for each row.

Comment: OK - I think my problem was (after looking at it a couple hours later) if I got multiple results from SQL it would be two arrays. I'm going to go ahead and accept your answer thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is looping twice because you have 2 elements in $query and you're setting $report_id and $looper inside the loop, which seems kind of pointless as you're not using $value anywhere.

Good luck!